# Show SKU on product add to cart alert notification

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

Is there a way to add product SKU on add to cart alert notification right now it shows the product name and I want to display the SKU also.
Please see the attached screenshot. http://prntscr.com/l7cfjx

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your Magento version 2.2.2. We just need to override the add to cart controller: `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add`

In `execute` method, we need to change the message (line 123 ~ 130)

```
     $message = __(
                    'You added %1 SKU: %2 to your shopping cart.',
                    $product->getName(),
                    $product->getSku()
                );
```

Later versions (for example 2.3), there are two places we need to change.

In `execute` method, we need to change

```
  $this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
                        'addCartSuccessMessage',
                        [
                            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                            'product_sku' => $product->getSku(),
                            'cart_url' => $this->getCartUrl(),
                        ]
                    );
```

We also need to change the template:
`view/frontend/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml`

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added %1 , SKU: %2 to your <a href="%3">shopping cart</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('product_sku')
    $block->getData('cart_url'),
), ['a']);
```